# Evaluating the bounds of integral

Tags: calculus

Given that $$f(x)\leq C\epsilon^{-1}\int^1_x(1+\epsilon^{-k}e^{-\alpha(1-t)/\epsilon})e^{-\alpha(t-x)/\epsilon}dt.$$ I want to show that $$f(x)\leq C(1+\epsilon^{-(k+1)}e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}).$$On evaluating  the integral I get $$f(x)\leq C\left(\epsilon(1-e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon})/\alpha+(1-x)\epsilon^{-k}e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}\right)$$How do I proceed?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the values of $\alpha$, $\epsilon$ or $k$?

Comment: @JohnM, $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, $\alpha>0$

Comment: Actually when you evaluated your integral you seem to be missing the $\epsilon^{-1}$ term out front.  I'll have to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REVISED ANSWER
The evaluation of the integral is missing the factor $\epsilon^{-1}$ out front.  The correct integral evaluation is:
$$C\left((1-e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon})/\alpha + (1-x)\epsilon^{-(k+1)}e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}\right).$$
You would like to show the inequality,
$$C\left((1-e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon})/\alpha + (1-x)\epsilon^{-(k+1)}e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}\right) \leq C\left(1+\epsilon^{-(k+1)} e^{-\alpha(1-x)/\epsilon}\right).$$

But this would seem impossible for sufficiently small $\alpha$.  For example, take $\alpha = \epsilon = 0.1$ and $x = 0$.  Then the left hand side will be greater than the right hand side.

I'm sorry I didn't catch your integration mistake sooner.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but could you establish the weaker bound.